# About Proposition 7.2 of Atiyah Mcdonald

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I'm studying commutative algebra and I got to the point where I'm studying noetherian rings. We say a ring is noetherian as a ring if it is noetherian as a module over himself.

Now, the proposition above states that if $A$ is a noetherian ring, and also a subring of $B$, and $B$ is finitely generated as an $A$-module, then $B$ is also noetherian as a ring.

The proof states that since $B$ is noetherian as an $A$-module, it is as a $B$-module, so the thesis is trivial. I can't understand why $B$ being noetherian as an $A$-module implies that it also is as a $B$-module. I think the one that makes most sense would be the way around since $A$ is included in $B$, and not viceversa. What am I missing here? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The book references (6.5) which says that if $M$ is a finitely generated $A$-module and $A$ is Noetherian, then $M$ is Noetherian. Now $M$ is Noetherian as an $A$-module.

So applied to your case, $B$ is a Noetherian $A$-module. But any ideal (aka $B$-submodule) of $B$ is an $A$-submodule of $B$. So certainly finitely generated. This implies $B$ is itself Noetherian as a $B$-module.